# How it works to make a SIP call in Android 5.1.1 without SipCallOptionHandler.java?

Tags: android, sip

In Android 4.4.4, `processIntent()` (in OutgoingCallBroadcaster.java) can call `startSipCallOptionHandler()` and then start `SipCallOptionHandler` to make SIP call.

But in Android 5.1.1, there is no code in `startSipCallOptionHandler()` function. And even `SipCallOptionHandler.java` is gone.

```
private void startSipCallOptionHandler(Context context, Intent intent,
        Uri uri, String number) {
    // TODO: Remove this code.
}
```

I wanna know, how it works to make a SIP call in Android 5.1.1.

[startSipCallOptionHandler() in OutgoingCallBroadcaster.java, Android 4.4.4](http://androidxref.com/4.4.4_r1/xref/packages/services/Telephony/src/com/android/phone/OutgoingCallBroadcaster.java#308)
[startSipCallOptionHandler() in OutgoingCallBroadcaster.java, Android 5.1.1](http://androidxref.com/5.1.1_r6/xref/packages/services/Telephony/src/com/android/phone/OutgoingCallBroadcaster.java#311)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find that `OutgoingCallBroadcaster.java` has been disabled in Android 5.0

```
<activity android:name="OutgoingCallBroadcaster"
    android:enabled="false"
```

`CallActivity.java` will handle the `android.intent.action.CALL` instead of `OutgoingCallBroadcaster.java` to accomplish the things.